# Could not set essentials permission?

Tags: java, permissions, bukkit, user-permissions

I want to add permission `"essentials.fly"` to a player.
Here is my code so far:

```
PermissionAttachment attachment = Player.addAttachment(Plugin);
attachment.setPermission("essentials.fly", true);
```

Problem is that `Player.hasPermission("essentials.fly")` returns `true` but player gets denied when executes the command.

Comment: I found no errors in your code. Where did you put `Player.hasPermission("essentials.fly")`?

Comment: idk if if perm is correct

Comment: This was not my question.

Comment: When do you use this command?

Comment: after onJoin where i am setting the perm

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this should work. Make sure that you have registered the listener and that you have @EventHandler before your onJoin() method.